# How can i add 'vue.js' to webpack's bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

i'm trying to add 'vue' in my 'webpack' bundle.js
but i doesn't work...

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js',
    }
};
```

entry.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        msg: 'Hello, Vue!'
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vue Study</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ msg }}
        </div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[index.html on chrome & dev-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWyH8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue 2.2 now per default uses ES6 modules, but despite it was pointed in the other answer as wrong, you can still use CommonJS if you want, so is not wrong do `require('vue')`, however, is recommended to switch to the new syntax.

You can do:

`var Vue = require('vue').default;`

or

`import Vue from 'vue';`

The last works without the `default` property, because the new ES6 syntax does this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now i can use 'Vue' constructor on 'entry.js' but on 'index.html'.
And i got new error message.

`[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build. 
(found in <Root>`

Answer (score -1):

You should replace

```
var Vue = require('vue')
```

by

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't a problem since Webpack is able to handle CommonJS imports.

Comment: @EdmundoRodrigues "require" is not a problem, but in this case, import solve the issue
and I find the use of "import" more logical in this case as it is a main dependency and it will be hoisted at the top of the final bundle. My answer is correct, and your downvote isn't justified

Comment: Sure, but when you say "should replace" it's like using in that way is wrong. Your answer solved the problem but didn't explain why.